# Integral of product of Bessel functions of first kind and different order and argument

Tags: special-functions, inner-products, bessel-functions

The problem: -The solution of the integral of Bessel functions of first kind, but different order and argument is not well placed among the literature. There is no clarification of how this general integral works and if there is a closed form solution:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{r}J_{m}(\alpha_{1}z)J_{n}(\alpha_{2}z)z \text{d}z
\end{equation}

in particular, the case of $m>0$ and $n=0$. While $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ are allowed to be complex or real.

Obs: I tried to find something related on the works of Watson, Lebedev, Korenev and Gray et al but to no avail...

Comment: Parameter $r$ is not needed here: $$\int_{0}^{r}J_{m}(\alpha_{1}z)J_{n}(\alpha_{2}z)z dz=r^2 \int_{0}^{1}J_{m}(a_1 z)J_{n}(a_2 z)z dz$$ where $$a=\alpha r$$

Comment: I was wondering if there is something relating the Hankel transform, i.e.:         \begin{equation}
lim_{r\rightarrow\infty} \left(   \int_{0}^{r}J_{m}(\alpha_{1}z)J_{n}(\alpha_{2}z)z dz \right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{m}(\alpha_{1}z)J_{n}(\alpha_{2}z)z dz
\end{equation}

Comment: I see. Essentially, $r$ is needed in case you want to take the limit to infinity, otherwise it can be taken as $1$ without the loss of generality

Comment: Aside from searching, what else have you tried? The series representation, the recurrence relations, the integral representation?

Comment: I tried to get a relationship with the following equation:          
 \begin{equation}                                                                                                            \int_{0}^{\infty}J_{m}(\alpha_{1}z)J_{n}(\alpha_{2}z)z^{-\lambda} dz                    \end{equation}  which is given as a function of a hypergeometric   series. The $\lambda$ can be zero. Then trying to substitute the hypergeometric series in the integrand, but to no avail...!